# how can i make the scroll bar of the page appear when i zoom the page in?

Tags: html

How can i make the scroll bar of the page appear when I zoom in on the page?

I had a page contain tables and when I zoom in the page I can't see some information until I zoom out.

Why is the page not showing the horizontal scroll bar?

Answer (score 2):

Put in your css:

overflow:auto;

You must add it to the desired target, i.e., the body or other specific element:

```
body {
    overflow:auto;
}

#target {
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work this is the full page code [http://jsfiddle.net/buffon/CfMPS/](http://jsfiddle.net/buffon/CfMPS/)

Comment: i tried it but it works only when i get the end of the page then the horizontal scroll bar appear

Comment: Did you get the answer? I am facing this issue